# How to generate a running number of sales in PHP

Tags: php

How to write the running number Sales order by the date in PHP. For example: start from Date (YYMMDD) + Running number (0001,0002,0003 and so on.....) = YYMMDD0001. On this by one click a send running number will +1.

Example:
Todays: 
2012230001
2012230002
2012230003
......
The Next Day:
2012240001
2012240002
2012230003
.....

The Code I tried

```
$Date = date("Ymd");
for ($i = 0; $i <= 999; $i++) {
    $Number = sprintf("%04d", $i);
}
$TTLCode2 = $Date . $Number;
echo $TTLCode2;
```

It Shows This

> 2012230999

How to I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the number in a database table and select max(number) where createdate = today

For example, in your db, add a "runningnumber" (integer) field.

and then in your query, use

```
select max(runningnumber) as maxnumber from dbtable where createdate = 'XXXX/XX/XX'
```

(XXXX/XX/XX) is today date

after that add 1 to the maxnumber and insert into your new record, make sure you add some "0" as prefix to your number so that the format will be 20XXXXXX000nn

Comment: which means that need create the database, then key in the one is Date and another is running number, then take the max(running number) and check the date it was today, then +1 to the running number and saving to the database?

Comment: Yes, this is a rather standard way to do it.